# How can I receive, parse RTP packets from DVR with php? (RTSP streaming)

Tags: php

So my goal is to able to receive and interpret rtp stream from Digital Video Recorder(DVR).
My RTSP initial tcp messages and responses are the following:

```
OPTIONS:

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=1000
Public: DESCRIBE, SETUP, TEARDOWN, PLAY, PAUSE, SET_PARAMETER
Connection: Keep-Alive

DESCRIBE:

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 1
Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.0.99:554/live/mpeg4/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 225

v=0
o=- 1 1 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Test
a=type:broadcast
t=0 0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/90000
a=fmtp:96 profile-level-id=3;config=00000100000001200086C4007B0C581120518F
a=control:track0

SETUP:

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=6970-6971;server_port=58132-58133
Session: 53A2D8BBA38F6D61979B8C323CB4A1

PLAY:

RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Session: 53A2D8BBA38F6D61979B8C323CB4A1
Range: npt=now-
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://192.168.0.99:554/live/mpeg4/track0;seq=58938;rtptime=388948125
```

After this successfufl initial steps the DVR should enable bitstream via RTP protocol but in the wireshark I don't see any rtp messages (filter:rtp)

How can I receive and interpret rtp stream with php? 
Furthermore I should be able to get images from given time intervals.
I would appreciate if you could give some ideas.